# How often does a database view get updated in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, view

Assume I have a view in MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW blah AS
  SELECT columnA FROM tableA
```

How often does this view get updated from the underlying table, tableA?

Answer (score 11):

Instantly. Views don't really exist as separate copies of the data, instead they exist as instructions to rewrite queries.

That is, when you `select columnA from blah`, MySQL internally rewrites that as `select columnA from tableA`.

In systems that support *materialized views*, the database is responsible for keeping them up to date.

(Note that when the query is complicated enough, MySQL will internally materialize a view, just for the duration of the query. This is an implementation detail and best considered a defect in MySQL's query optimizer. `EXPLAIN` can be used to see when this is happening—but you will very likely notice from the terrible performance.)